# JS: Chart width changed after Drop Down Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added DropDown Selection option to select between different chart datasets (for same graph type) and selection menu it is working properly, however chart width somehow shrink at selection of options that are by default "invisible".

I'm struggling to find an error with no success in following code.

HTML:

```
 <select id="target">
            <option value="sankey_1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="sankey_2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="sankey_3">Option 3</option>
        </select>

        <div id="sankey_1"; class="vis"></div>
        <div id="sankey_2"; class="inv"></div>
        <div id="sankey_3"; class="inv"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.inv {
  display: none;
}
.vis {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['sankey']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'From');
        data.addColumn('string', 'To');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
        data.addRows([
          [ 'A', 'X', 5 ],
          [ 'A', 'Y', 7 ],
          [ 'A', 'Z', 6 ],
          [ 'B', 'X', 2 ],
          [ 'B', 'Y', 9 ],
          [ 'B', 'Z', 4 ]
        ]);


        // Instantiates and draws our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById('sankey_1'));
        chart.draw(data);
      }

      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['sankey']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1);

      function drawChart1() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'From');
        data.addColumn('string', 'To');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
        data.addRows([
          [ 'A', 'X', 5 ],
          [ 'A', 'Y', 7 ],
          [ 'A', 'Z', 6 ],
          [ 'B', 'X', 2 ],
          [ 'B', 'Y', 9 ],
          [ 'B', 'Z', 4 ]
        ]);


        // Instantiates and draws our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById('sankey_2'));
        chart.draw(data);
      }

      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['sankey']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart2);

      function drawChart2() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'From');
        data.addColumn('string', 'To');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
        data.addRows([
          [ 'A', 'X', 5 ],
          [ 'A', 'Y', 7 ],
          [ 'A', 'Z', 6 ],
          [ 'B', 'X', 2 ],
          [ 'B', 'Y', 9 ],
          [ 'B', 'Z', 4 ]
        ]);


        // Instantiates and draws our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById('sankey_3'));
        chart.draw(data);
      }


      $(window).resize(function(){
        drawChart();
        drawChart1();
        drawChart2();

      });

              document
                .getElementById('target')
                .addEventListener('change', function () {
                        'use strict';
                        var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),
                                target = document.getElementById(this.value);
                        if (vis !== null) {
                                vis.className = 'inv';
                        }
                        if (target !== null ) {
                                target.className = 'vis';
                        }
                });
```

Comment: The chart needs to be redrawn after the class is switched

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, that work for me.

Here is modified part of code.

```
    document
            .getElementById('target')
            .addEventListener('change', function () {
                    'use strict';
                    var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),
                            target = document.getElementById(this.value);
                    if (vis !== null) {
                            vis.className = 'inv';
                    }
                    if (target !== null ) {
                            target.className = 'vis';
                                    drawChart();
                                    drawChart1();
                                    drawChart2();
                    }
            });
```